# Libsignal-Client Error while using "Signal-Cli" on Linux

Tags: linux, desktop, messenger

When trying to register in Signal-Desktop app via signal-cli-0.8.4.1, I get the following error message in Linux Mint 19.1 terminal:

`Missing required native library dependency: libsignal-client`

Unfortunately I am not a pro Linux user, so I would be very grateful, if someone can provide a robust instruction to overcome this issue?

What I have done so far:

1. Download and unpack signal-cli-0.8.4.1.tar.gz from GitHub.
2. Open the terminal and open the respective directory via `$ cd Downloads/signal-cli-0.8.4.1/`
3. Enter command to register: `$ bin/signal-cli -u MY_NUMBER register` (which results in the error message above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changelog mentions that with version 0.8.0 of the signal-cli there is a native library of libsignal-client required. See e.g. https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli/blob/v0.8.2/CHANGELOG.md which provides a link to https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli/wiki/Provide-native-lib-for-libsignal to solve this.

Comment: I am afraid, that would be the solution ;-). - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Following the build instructions provided at https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli/wiki/Provide-native-lib-for-libsignal didn't work for me, but the instructions from bublath at https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli/issues/661 gave me something that did.

Here's the procedure I used:

```
VERSION="0.8.4"
wget https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli/releases/download/v$VERSION/signal-cli-$VERSION.tar.gz
tar xzf signal-cli-$VERSION.tar.gz
rm signal-cli-$VERSION.tar.gz

git clone https://github.com/signalapp/zkgroup.git
cd zkgroup/ffi/java && make
# Ignore error messages
cd ../../target/release
zip -u ../../../signal-cli-$VERSION/lib/zkgroup-java-*.jar libzkgroup.so

git clone https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-client.git
cd libsignal-client/java/ && ./build_jni.sh desktop
cd ../target/release
zip -u ../../../signal-cli-$VERSION/lib/signal-client-java-*.jar libsignal_jni.so
```